# What the third thing between true and false discord.js

Tags: javascript

i don't know what the third thing between true and false in discord.js

[image: preview]

```
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: ??? })
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of discord js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/typedef/PermissionOverwriteOptions), it means `null` or "unset"

Comment: thanks, its working ! <3

Comment: Please approve the answer if it helped :)